# ADODB COPY RECORDS FROM CSV TO XLSM

Tags: vba, csv, adodb

Hi I am trying to get some data from csv file using adodb. Trying to copy the record to current worksheet I am able to copy the headers but not the records below from the source file

Some help would be really appreciated.

```
    Public Sub ConnectExcel()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim str As String
Dim recCount As Long
Dim fc As Long
Dim ic As Integer
Dim ir As Integer


Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


'***********CONNECTION TO THE FILE********************'
With cn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\tmp\;Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited';"
.Open .ConnectionString
End With


'***********READING RECORDS********************'
str = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [prod.csv] WHERE [Netting Agreement Type]='GROSS'"

rs.Open str, cn
rs.MoveFirst
While Not rs.EOF
    recCount = recCount + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Wend


'***********COPY RECORDS********************'
fc = rs.Fields.Count

For ic = 1 To fc
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, ic).Value = rs.Fields(ic - 1).Name
Next
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs



'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
'Print rs.RecordCount


'***********CLOSE CONNECTIONS AND RELESE REFERENCES********************'
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Sorry might have additional code as kept working on it but hopefully might help someone else one day.

```
Public Sub ConnectExcel()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim str As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String
Dim imm As Variant
Dim cem As Variant
Dim ic As Integer

'***********CONNECTION TO THE FILE********************'

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With cn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\tmp\;Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited';"
.Open .ConnectionString
End With


'***********READING RECORDS FROM CSV AND STORING THEM TO VARIANTS********************'
'str = "SELECT TOP 10 I.*, C.* FROM [hkmaimm.csv] I INNER JOIN [hkmacem.csv] C ON I.[Counterparty ID] = C.[Counterparty ID] AND I.[ï»¿Saracen] = C.[ï»¿Saracen]"

'***********READ AND STORE IMM CONTEXT********************'
'str1 = "SELECT TOP 500 * FROM [hkmaimm.csv]"
str1 = "SELECT * FROM [hkmaimm.csv]"
rs.Open str1, cn
imm = rs.GetRows()
fc = rs.Fields.Count
For ic = 1 To fc
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, ic).value = rs.Fields(ic - 1).Name
Next
fc = 0
rs.Close

'***********READ AND STORE CEM CONTEXT********************'
'str2 = "SELECT TOP 500 * FROM [hkmacem.csv]"
str2 = "SELECT * FROM [hkmacem.csv]"
rs.Open str2, cn
cem = rs.GetRows()
fc = rs.Fields.Count
For ic = 1 To fc
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, ic).value = rs.Fields(ic - 1).Name
Next
rs.Close

Call CalculateLGDchange(imm, cem)


'***********COPY RECORDS********************'
'
'rs.MoveFirst
'RowCount = 2
'While Not rs.EOF
'    For col = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
'        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, col) = rs(col - 1)
'    Next col
'    RowCount = RowCount + 1
'    rs.MoveNext
'Wend
'


'***********CLOSE CONNECTIONS AND RELEASE REFERENCES********************'

cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```